# boost::property_tree passing subtree including <xmlattr>

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm trying to pass elements of a boost::property_tree::ptree to a function. 
In detail, I have to following XML code from which a ptree is initialised:

```
<Master Name='gamma'>
    <Par1 Name='name1'>
        <Value>0.</Value>
        <Fix>1</Fix>
    </Par1>
    <Par2 Name='name2'>
        <Value>0.</Value>
        <Fix>1</Fix>
    </Par2>
</Master>
```

I would like to pass part of it to a function. Basically I want to pass:

```
   <Par2 Name='name2'>
        <Value>0.</Value>
        <Fix>1</Fix>
    </Par2>
```

The function could look like this:

```
 void processTree( which_type_do_I_put_here element ){
     std::string n = element.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.Name");
     double val = element.get<double>("Value");
 }
```

In general I could pass a subtree using `ptree::get_child("par2")`. This has the disadvantage that the function has no access to `<xmlattr>` of this node.

How can I pass this part of the tree with access to `<xmlattr>`?
Thanks in advance for any ideas.

~Peter

Comment: `<xmlattr>` is nothing special, it's just a child tree. So `get_child("par2")` simply returns a tree that has an `<xmlattr>` child tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type is a `ptree`.

> In general I could pass a subtree using ptree::get_child("par2").

Indeed.

> This has the disadvantage that the function has no access to  of this node

That's not right:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/810482276e9ff069)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

std::string const sample = R"(
<Master Name='gamma'>
    <Par1 Name='name1'>
        <Value>0.</Value>
        <Fix>1</Fix>
    </Par1>
    <Par2 Name='name2'>
        <Value>0.</Value>
        <Fix>1</Fix>
    </Par2>
</Master>
)";

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

void processTree(ptree const& element) {
     std::string n = element.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.Name");

     double val = element.get<double>("Value");
     std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": n=" << n << " val=" << val << "\n";
}

int main() {
    ptree pt;
    {
        std::istringstream iss(sample);
        read_xml(iss, pt);
    }

    processTree(pt.get_child("Master.Par2"));
}
```

Which prints:

```
processTree: n=name2 val=0
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I tried to implement this before and for some reasons which I do not recall it didn't work. Thanks a lot!